# Videos are placed on top of images in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view which is populated with videos or images, based on what is fetched from firebase.

I am having this problem where when I fetch the data and add to the cells, some cells get a video added on top [of the image].

*I have looked through the code found bellow and cant seem to . find where the problem is coming from.*

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "p1Item", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

    if postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].image != nil { //its an image

        let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: postArray[indexPath.row].media[0].postNum!, isItForP3: false).getDate!

        do {                
            cell.imageView.image = postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].image!

            if postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrl != "" {
                let url = URL(string: "\(postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrl)")
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

                if let profileImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    cell.profImage.image = profileImage
                    cell.titleLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.item].user.username
                    cell.subtitleLabel.text = date
                }
            } else {
                //I add a fake image here
                cell.titleLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.item].user.username
                cell.subtitleLabel.text = date
                cell.profImage.image = UIImage(named: "media")
            }

        } catch {
            print("need to add stuff to this catch")
        }

    } else { //its a video

        let videoURL = postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].videoURL

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds
        cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].postNum!, isItForP3: false).getDate!

        do {
            if postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrl != "" {
                let url = URL(string: "\(postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrl)")
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
                if let profileImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    cell.profImage.image = profileImage
                    cell.titleLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.item].user.username
                    cell.subtitleLabel.text = date
                }
            } else {
                //I add a fake profile image here
                cell.titleLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.item].user.username
                cell.subtitleLabel.text = date
                cell.profImage.image = UIImage(named: "media")
            }
        } catch {
            print("need to add stuff to this catch")
        }
    }

    print("Completed: ", cell.imageView!)

    return cell
}
```

**How do i fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is here

```
 cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

you should clear the cell because it's dequeued

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "p1Item", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1
cell.layer.sublayers.forEach {
  if $0 is AVPlayerLayer {
    $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
  }
}
```

, also you shouldn't use

```
 let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
```

for remote data gribbing , you may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: So i tried this and for teh last item in teh collection view the video view apeared ontop 1/3 times i tested. How I implemnted: [what you provided in example] all right at the top of teh method

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "p1Item", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1
```

This means that you are reusing the old cell and in your case the old cell might have a `AVPlayerLayer`

One way to fix this is to use different `withReuseIdentifier`

```
if postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].image != nil { //its an image
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImgageCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

       return cell

    } else { //its a video
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

       return cell   
    }
}
```

Or reset the Cell before reuse i.e. remove the layer after `dequeueReusableCell`